# Laravel/Eloquent: Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, package, eloquent, composer-php

I'm building a package in Laravel 4 but am getting a non-object error when attempting to access the db from which seems to be a properly instantiated object. Here's the setup:

The config and class in question:

**composer.json:**

```
...
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "Vendor\\Chat": "src/vendor/chat/src"
        }  
    }
...
```

**The class:**

```
namespace Vendor\Chat;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;


class ChatHistory extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'chat_history';

    protected $fillable = array('message', 'user_id', 'room_token');

    public function __construct($attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

}
```

**The call:**

```
$message = new Message($msg);

$history = new ChatHistory;
$history->create(array(
                 'room_token' => $message->getRoomToken(),
                 'user_id' => $message->getUserId(),
                 'message' => $message->getMessage(),
              ));
```

**The error:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function connection() on a non-object in /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 2894
```

I believe I'm missing something fundamental and under my nose. Thanks for any and all help!

EDIT:

Here is the class that's instantiating ChatHistory and calling the write:

```
namespace Vendor\Chat;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

use Vendor\Chat\Client;
use Vendor\Chat\Message;
use Vendor\Chat\ChatHistory;

use Illuminate\Database\Model;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {

    protected $app;

    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $client = new Client;
        $client->setId($conn->resourceId);
        $client->setSocket($conn);

        $this->clients->attach($client);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg) 
    {
        $message = new Message($msg);

        $history = new ChatHistory;
        ChatHistory::create(array(
                     'room_token' => $message->getRoomToken(),
                     'user_id' => $message->getUserId(),
                     'message' => $message->getMessage(),
                  ));
        /* error here */
        /* ... */ 
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) 
    {
        $conn->close();
    }

    protected function getClientByConn(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        foreach($this->clients as $client) {
            if($client->getSocket() === $conn) {
                return $client;
            } 
        } 

        return null;
    }
}
```

The fact that DB isn't available suggest that Eloquent isn't being loaded up top?

Comment: In which line you get this error? Is it for history or using a method for `$message`. We or course don't know that and we don't know what `Message` is

Comment: Apologies. The error fires upon calling create() on ChatHistory. Message is a simple class to represent a socket message.

Comment: Did you try booting Laravel like described at https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=969-codeception-and-laravel/0?

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4.1 or 4.2?

Comment: @Ramin I'm using 4.2

Comment: @TonyStark I have not tried that, no. I'll see if I can get the test scenario to work with my current issue and report back ASAP.

Comment: **1)** From where are you making the `$history->create` call? **2)** If you `dd($history)` just after `$history = new ChatHistory;`, what do you get?

Comment: @J.LaRosee Apart from the fact that `create()` is meant for static usage, the problem is likely not related to the `$history` object. Instead, it really seems like the connection resolver (static property of `Model`) is not set. If you're relying on the DatabaseServiceProvider, it's probably not booted correctly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Answer**:

Bootstrap your package in your service provider's `boot` method.

---

**Explanation**:

Since you're developing a package to be used with Laravel, there's no point in making your own `Capsule` instance. You can just use `Eloquent` directly.

Your problem seems to stem from `DB`/`Eloquent` not being set up yet by the time your code hits it.

You have not shown us your service provider, but I'm guessing you're using one and doing it all in the `register` method.

Since your package depends on a different service provider (`DatabaseServiceProvider`) to be wired up prior to its own execution, the correct place to bootstrap your package is in your service provider's `boot` method.

Here's a quote from [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#service-providers):

> The `register` method is called immediately when the service provider is registered, while the `boot` command is only called right before a request is routed.
>
> So, if actions in your service provider rely on another service provider already being registered [...] you should use the `boot` method.

Comment: Here goes the bounty! I did guess we were just missing some statement in the docs... always read it carefully!

Comment: Employing the Capsule "fixed" the issue but it appears to be a less-than-optimal solution (https://github.com/illuminate/database). Looking to bootstrap the package is what I was looking for, looks like, though the Capsule solution helped get me on the right path by showing me that the code isn't the issue, the order in which I was loading and using code was incorrect.

Answer (score 22):

In case you're working with Lumen, you may occur identical problem. In this case just uncomment:

```
// $app->withFacades();

// $app->withEloquent();
```

in `bootstrap\app.php`

Comment: Just the case :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

@matpop and @TonyStark were on the right track: Capsule\Manager wasn't being booted.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'project',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);

// Set the event dispatcher used by Eloquent models... (optional)
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;

$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

I am able to extend Eloquent after booting. I think another solution might be along the lines of (but not tested):

```
include __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/start.php';
$app->boot();
```

Comment: Are you developing a **stand-alone** package which uses Eloquent or are you building a package that's _specifically intended for use with Laravel_?

Comment: It's a package that's specific for Laravel.

Comment: @matpop Your suggestion got me onto the right track so I'd like to give you the bounty. Not sure how to go about that, given you've not provided an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation, it's worth much more than SO rep so don't worry about it. Actually, at this stage I think no one yet deserves the bounty, cause it seems you fixed the problem with Capsule for now, and I believe it's not the best way for a package specific for Laravel. If all is setup correctly, the service providers of such packages are loaded by the underlying Laravel app _after_ the "normal" service providers are already booted (including the DatabaseServiceProvider), so you shouldn't need Capsule nor explicitly call `$app->boot()` (which is already called).

Comment: Have you followed [the official guide](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages)? Sorry if I won't be there for a while, my timezone is at the other side of the ocean :)

Comment: @matpop, that's what I was wondering. If this is a Laravel package, using Capsule (even if it gets the code to work) shouldn't be necessary and is masking some other problem. @J.LaRosee, what happens if you include `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` and try to access the `DB` object, i.e. `DB::table('chat_history')`?

Answer (score 2):

What i did was simple, i just forgot to uncomment `$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();` in my bootstrap/app.php.

Now works fine

Comment: This fixed it for me, but this is for Lumen.

Answer (score 1):

Try including the DB facade as well as Eloquent...

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
```

...and then see if you have access to `DB::table('chat_history')`.

(Also note that in your class, your call to `use Illuminate\Database\Model;` should be `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;` )

Answer (score 0):

you must use

```
$capsule->`bootEloquent`();
```

in `database.php` / after your connection.

this is your full codes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->`addConnection`([
    'driver' => `'mysql'`,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'test1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
]);

$capsule->`bootEloquent`();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use App\Setting;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;



class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);


        $settings = Setting::all();
        foreach ($settings as $key => $settings) {
            if($key === 0) $system_name = $setting->value;
            elseif($key === 1) $favicon = $setting->value;
            elseif($key === 2) $front_logo = $setting->value;
            elseif($key === 3) $admin_logo = $setting->value;
        }
        $shareData = array(
            'system_name'=>$system_name,
            'favicon'=>$favicon,
            'front_logo'=>$front_logo,
            'admin_logo'=>$admin_logo
        );
        view()->share('shareData',$shareData);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.