# Laravel Database Connection

Tags: laravel

My application was built using Laravel. I got an error which shown on occassion.

> FatalErrorException in Model.php line 3335: 
>   Call to a member function connection() on null

On model.php line 3335, there is :

```
public static function resolveConnection($connection = null)
{
   return static::$resolver->connection($connection);
}
```

How do I troubleshoot/fix the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680716/laravel-eloquent-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-connection-on-a-non-o

Comment: Are you sure it's the same issue as the link you provided?

Comment: I posted it in hope that it may give you an idea on how to resolve it. If it was the issue, it would be marked as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally be able to solve the issue. 
I'm using Cartalyst Sentinel for my auth and moving the providers to the bottom of the list resolve the issue.
I think it must be put below the AuthServiceProvider