# Accessing Eloquent ORM inside Ratchet's MessageComponentInterface

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, eloquent, ratchet

The title is confusing. Basically, I'm unable to access Laravel's utilities in classes that don't belong to the framework.

Error is: `Call to a member function connection() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\blazocket\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Databas e\Eloquent\Model.php:1571`

I have a Websocket Server based on Ratchet library, it has the following strucutre:

```
namespace App\Http\Websockets;
$server = new \Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080);
$server->route('/api/socket', new WebSocketHandler, array('*'));
```

Snippet from WebSocketHandler:

```
namespace App\Http\Websockets;
use App\Models\Website;

class WebSocketHandler implements MessageComponentInterface {



    protected $apis;
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->refreshDatabase();
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    private function refreshDatabase(){
      $this->apis = Website::all();
    }

}
```

I've tried doing this:

```
$app = require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../../../bootstrap/app.php';
$app->boot();
```

But It's not the solution (I tried it from a different SO issue). Also, I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680716/laravel-eloquent-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-connection-on-a-non-o), but I'm not sure about the way I could implement the "bootstraping" thing.

I'm aware that the error is happening because there's no connection between the class (WebSocketHandler) and the Laravel framework. I've tried every answer, and checking the docs, I couldn't find a way on my own to make this class connected.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So basically, you have a Laravel project and you installed Ratchet with composer require inside the Laravel project?

If yes - you should composer dump-autoload.

If no - and you installed elsewhere - there's no point in thinking it's not working due to some missing things. It's not working because they are different projects and use different autoloaders from /vendor/composer.
I'd suggest to install it inside the laravel project. But, if you can not do that, you can create a new composer project. Require ratchet and add the path for autoloading, with the full path of the laravel project.

Comment: did you declare a namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed declaring the namespace. As you see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680716/laravel-eloquent-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-connection-on-a-non-o)

there's a namespace declaration.

Comment: I have it already in the original file, but still, it's not working.

Comment: Can   you post exactly what you have?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer that you need to boot (Idk the correct term) Laravel and make it available for custom classes that have nothing to do with Laravel.

I do have this way for the database connection only. First, add these on the top of your class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
```

Then, create a new method in your class and call it once you initialize it.

```
private function setupLaravel(){
  $capsule = new Capsule;
  $capsule->addConnection([
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'database' => 'mydatabase',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => "",
  ]);
  $capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));
  $capsule->setAsGlobal();
  $capsule->bootEloquent();
}
```

If you're running Ratchet and want to access the DB via Eloquent ORM, this is the way.